# How can I update the video dynamically in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this is working with one video but I have 3 thumbnails and what I want is to update the video once I click over the thumbnail.

So this is the code that I have and I guess somehow I should put the video names in an array. But how do I call the video from array?

```
function playVideo(){
    if(!vidInitialized){
        vidInitialized = true;
        $("#video").append( "<source src='video/video1.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>" );   
        $("#video").append( "<source src='video/video1.webm' type='video/webm'></video>" );
        initVideo('pause');
    }else{
        video.currentTime=0;
    }
}

function addEventListeners() {
    document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("click", playVideo);
    document.getElementById("video2").addEventListener("click", playVideo);
    document.getElementById("video3").addEventListener("click", playVideo);         
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a complete working example, with your HTML too?

Comment: you need to play all vedio at on click

Comment: my question is how to update the video not how to play it. so for example if I create an array with video1 video2 video 3 and instead the video name I have videos[0] videos[1] videos[2] how do I change this when I click on thumbnail

Comment: you have three thumbnail

Comment: yes thats why I have 3 ids like video1 video 2 video3

Comment: How about using a data-* element on each thumbnail that contains the link to the video and pass that data-* element to a single video load function. 
I'll do this in jQuery for simplicity:

$("video1").addEventListener("click", playVideo);
var url = $(this).